# SpringDoc app-doc.yaml don't show the swagger doc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I have a API with swagger. Endpoint example:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns a list of Pix transactions.",httpMethod = "POST",response = DResponse.class)
@PostMapping("/transactions")
public ResponseEntity<DResponse> getTransactions(@RequestBody PixTransactionRequest pixTransactionRequest) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pixService.getTransactionsPix(pixTransactionRequest));
}
```

My swagger page show me all the info correctly:

[image]

But when I tryed generate a yaml doc this description don't works. I dont see the description of the endpoint (Returns a list of Pix transactions.) in my yaml doc:

```
/api/pix/transactions:
post:
  tags:
  - pix-controller
  operationId: getTransactions
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/PixTransactionRequest'
```

Comment: The question is based on [How to integrate Swagger with SpringDoc YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503634/how-to-integrate-swagger-with-springdoc-yaml).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using Swagger 1.x annotation `@ApiOperation` with Springdoc while the supported Swagger specification is Swagger 2.x (aka the OpenAPI Specification)

As for the solution to this, use the `@Operation` annotation to get the expected output.

Note that it's not possible to speicify the return type with the new annotation. Thus to achieve the same functionality you need to re-write your swagger annotation as below

```java
// Describe the Operation
@Operation(summary = "Returns a list of Pix transactions.", description = "Any long description about the endpoint that you want")
// Describe the Response of the Operation. Use the below way if only 1 type of response will be returned by the endpoint
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(DResponse.class))})
```

If the endpoint can return more than 1 response, use the below approach

```java
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Created", content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(DResponse.class))}),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error", content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = MyErrorResponse.class))})
})
```

And there's no alternative for `httpMethod = "POST"` of the `@ApiOperation`. Swagger 2.x infers the type of operation by the type of request annotation placed on the method, i.e `@PostMapping` will give a POST request and so on. This rule still holds when you use `@RequestMapping` to specify the type of request method.